# Согласование с числительным, оканчивающимся на один

Tags: согласование, числительные, причастия

*Он объявил о пропаже 31 млн, собранного (собранных) на операцию* - какая форма причастия и почему должна употребляться? Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Он объявил о пропаже 31 млн., собранного на операцию. Только вот сокращение числительного допускается лишь при следующем существительном (рублей), здесь же нежелательно, тогда и вопроса о согласовании бы не возникло: о пропаже 31 миллиона, собранного...

Составное количественное числительное, оканчивающееся на один, согласуется в единственном числе со стоящим рядом существительным, причём, поскольку это числительное изменяется по родам (один, одна, одно), а слово миллион - грамматическое существительное муж. рода, то согласуется и в роде. Миллиона какого? - собранного.

Comment: Людмила, вы так сформулировали, что даже я засомневался, что вы сказать хотели. Если слова "рублей" не  опускать, *тридцати одного миллиона рублей, **собранных*** или *тридцати одного миллиона рублей, **собранного***??? Что-то я  сильно сомневаюсь, что второе правильно. )))

Comment: Я отвечаю на вопрос автора, там нет слова рублей, там сокращение млн. Корректно "...о пропаже 31 млн.рублей, собранных..."     Но: "...о пропаже 31 миллиона, собранного..."

Answer (score 1):

Если сказать с денежной единицей, то проблем не будет:

*Он объявил о пропаже 31 миллиона рублей, собранных на операцию.*

А если всё-таки в разговорной речи очень хочется опустить денежную единицу, то, наверно, правильно будет в единственном числе, *собранного.* Но я не уверен.

Comment: Не уверен в своём ответе?

Comment: Артем, спасибо за мнение. Я думаю, что возможно, поскольку здесь нет необходимости во множественном числе, как например в конструкции "победителями признаны 31 человек". Возможно ли употребление формы и множественного, и единственного числа - или для этого случая есть строгое правило и уместен только один из вариантов? Хотелось бы выяснить

Comment: Да, shampar, только не во всём ответе, а в последнем.

Comment: Не за что, Erine. *Хотелось бы выяснить.* Да, и мне интересно, подождём других ответов.